# Convert C# To NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js

Hi so am trying to convert this C# function to NodeJS but it does not work I don't really know what is wrong lemme show some code and outputs

C#:

```
private static byte[] ConvertMsg(byte[] message, byte type = 255, byte cmd = 255)
{
    int msgLength = message.Length;
    byte[] bArray = new byte[msgLength + 3];
    bArray[0] = type;
    bArray[1] = cmd;
    Buffer.BlockCopy(message, 0, bArray, 2, msgLength);
    bArray[msgLength + 2] = 0;
    return bArray;
}

static void Main()
{

    byte[] encrypted = ConvertMsg(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("hi"),3,3);
    Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted: {Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted)}");

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
AwNoaQA=
```

NodeJS:

```
function ConvertMsg(message, type=255, cmd=255){
    let length = message.length;
    let bArray = Buffer.alloc(length+3);
    bArray[0] = type;
    bArray[1] = cmd;

    bArray.copy(message,0,length);

    bArray[length + 2] = 0;
    return bArray;
}

let encrypted = ConvertMsg(Buffer.from("hi"),3,3);
console.log(encrypted.toString("base64"));
```

Output:

```
AwMAAAA=
```

As you can see the output is not the same any help is much appreciated, please explain when you answer I would like to learn more thank you.

Comment: As an aside, I hope you aren't using this to encrypt data as your variable names suggest.

Comment: Just learning need help with this so i can learn how Buffers work in NodeJS cause am stuck right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`Buffer` documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_copy_target_targetstart_sourcestart_sourceend), `.copy(target[, targetStart[, sourceStart[, sourceEnd]]])`

> Copies data from a region of buf to a region in target even if the target memory region overlaps with buf.

Here

```
// means copy 'bArray' starting from length to 'message' starting from 0
bArray.copy(message, 0, length);
```

You do not copy contents of `message` to `bArray`. You do the opposite thing - you copy `bArray` contents, which is `[3, 3, 0, 0, 0]` by now to `message`, and actually overwrite your message.

Then, you output this `bArray`, which results in `AwMAAAA=` which is Base64 representation of `[3, 3, 0, 0, 0]`.

You may want to change your function in this way:

```
function ConvertMsg(message, type=255, cmd=255){
    let length = message.length;
    let bArray = Buffer.alloc(length + 3);

    bArray[0] = type;
    bArray[1] = cmd;

    // means copy 'message' starting from 0 to 'bArray' starting from 2
    message.copy(bArray, 2);

    bArray[length + 2] = 0;
    return bArray;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you, Also thank you explaining just learnt something new.